# Context menu doesn't contain Scaffolding VS2015 ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm going through a tutorial on ASP.NET 5 documentation website.

As you can see [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html#add-scaffolding) the trainer right clicks on the `Controller` folder and he/she gets a context menu that under the `Add` sub menu there's a `New Scaffolded Item...` option.

But as you can see below there's no `New Scaffolded Item...` option available for me when I right click on my `Controller` folder!

[`New Scaffolded Item...` is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fefDz.jpg)

I also don't have `Add view...` option when I right click inside an action!

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Updade 1 CTP.

Comment: It's possible this tutorial was made using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RTM, which releases on November 30th and I believe includes MVC 6 scaffolding. Though that feature may also be in the preview versions that were available.

Comment: ASP.net 5 RC1 has scaffolding added. Its an separate download to Visual Studio 2015. You can download it here http://get.asp.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of Asp.Net 5 was to trim away as much functionality as possible and leave only what was 'absolutely essential' starting with .Net Core.

Productivity features like scaffolding don't seem to fall under that 'essential' umbrella and will need to be added as dependencies to your project.

This link might help: [Scaffolding MSDN Blog Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/21/command-line-scaffolding-for-asp-net-vnext.aspx).

One caveat: There are many classes that have been renamed from version '1.0.0-beta8 to 1.0.0-rc1-final. And I believe the CodeGenerator is one of them. 'Framework' changed to 'Extensions' within the namespace hierarchy.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you sir, this was very helpful.
I updated to 1.0.0.rc1.final and that fixed my problem.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Apparently scaffolding only works with entity framework 7.

Adding

> "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

to your project.json dependencies should bring back the scaffolding context menu entry...